# Read variable inside function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Right now I have three files, two javascript files and one html file that will call upon these two javascript files. Inside my first javascript file, let's call it part1.js, I have this content:

```
var dataval;
$.get('example.cgi', function(data){
    dataval = data;
});
```

Inside part2.js, I am trying to call on this dataval value. But it is not working, as I am assuming that dataval is inside the get function and is therefore a local value. Is there anyway I can grab that value? My html file is calling on both of these javascripts. Is there anyway I can access that variable?

Thanks!!

Comment: What's inside of part2.js? Please specify every file content.

Comment: `dataval` is most certainly not a "local" value in this case; only variables declared with a `var` keyword are in function scope. Your issue is because of the **A** in Ajax.

Comment: Oh, I will check out that link Juhana. Hopefully my problem will be fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem here with asynchronous calls. You should either use a callback function or make use of the jquery promise capability.

In your part1.js, you should instead define a function:

```
function callCgi(callback) {
    $.get('example.cgi', callback); //Callback will receive the data.
}
```

and then use it in part2.js:

```
callCgi(function(data) {
    //do something with data.
});
```

Or with promises:

```
function callCgi() {
    return $.get('example.cgi');
}
```

and then use it in part2.js:

```
callCgi().then(function(data) {
    //do something with data.
});
```

Comment: When it's an obvious dupe it's probably better to point to one of the question it duplicates. In this case there are a plethora of choices, unfortunately.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help you out :)